# Error the deployment function in lambda with graphene module

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, graphene-python

*[error when executing the function in aws lambda, while locally there is no error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4XsD.png)
When executing the code in AWS lambda this error arises, what I want is to be able to use graqpl to perform dynamodb queries and to use them.*

**Solution attempt:** uninstall typing from the python virtual environment.

Error that occurs:

```py
[ERROR] AttributeError: type object 'Callable' has no attribute '_abc_registry'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
    return load_source(name, filename, file)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = _load(spec)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/patron4.py", line 7, in <module>
    import graphene
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/graphene/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .types import (
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/graphene/types/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from graphql import ResolveInfo
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/graphql/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .graphql import graphql
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/graphql/graphql.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .execution import ExecutionResult
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/graphql/execution/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .executor import execute, subscribe
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/graphql/execution/executor.py", line 14, in <module>
    from promise import Promise, promise_for_dict, is_thenable
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/promise/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .promise import (
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/promise/promise.py", line 8, in <module>
    from typing import (List, Any, Callable, Dict, Iterator, Optional, # flake8: noqa
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/typing.py", line 1357, in <module>
    class Callable(extra=collections_abc.Callable, metaclass=CallableMeta):
  File "/tmp/sls-py-req/typing.py",enter code here line 1005, in __new__
    self._abc_registry = extra._abc_registry
```

Code used:

```py
class User(Model):
  class Meta:
    table_name = 'patron2'
    region = 'us-east-2'
    host = 'https://dynamodb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
  id = UnicodeAttribute(hash_key=True, null=False)
  discipline = UnicodeAttribute(null=False)


class UserNode(PynamoObjectType):
  class Meta:
    model = User
    interfaces = (graphene.Node,)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
  users = graphene.List(UserNode)
  def resolve_users(self, args, context, info):
    return list(User.scan())

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

def patrongrafico(event, context):
  # fetch all todos from the database
  try:
    print("hola")
    query = '''
        users {
          discipline
        }
      '''
    results = schema.execute(query)
    print(results)
  except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
  return {'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps({'items': [dict(result) for result in results]})}
```

Comment: Hey Max, please copy any error messages as text into the question and show us the code that created it.

Comment: okay, thanks your answer.

Comment: How did you package and deploy your code? Did you use any Framework for that?

Comment: Yes, with serverles framework.

Comment: Are you using the `serverless-python-requirements` plugin? I spent a few days figuring out that a library didn't like the `slim` packaging mode, it was working fine locally as well and only threw errors in AWS - let me know if that helped

Comment: I am actually using the fully serverless-python-requirements, how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the Serverless Framework in combination with the serverless-python-requirements plugin you should make sure, that slim packaging is off, as this interferes with some libraries. Essentially some libraries assume they're installed via a "real" package manager and in that case the directory layout and files look slightly different.

I was having this problem with the `jsonschema` package a few months ago and wrote about it in a [blog post](https://aws-blog.de/2019/09/automating-acm-certificates-with-serverless-framework.html) if you're interested (Full disclosure: this is the blog of my employer).

Essentially your `serverless.yml` as a `custom` section which you can use among other things to configure the plugins:

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    slim: true
```

The slim `true` parameter effectively removes some information that shouldn't be necessary for most libraries, but some rely on it. For information on this parameter see the package's [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements#slim-package).

Try again with this configuration:

```
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    slim: false
```

Comment: I have configured slim: false and the same error continues to appear. Additionally, I set the following configuration to skip the typing module without obtaining better results.
```pythonRequirements:
      zip: true
      slim: false
      noDeploy:
      - typing```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the error is to remove the version of Python 3.7 and implement 3.6, since Graphene does not support versions greater than 3.6.

Comment: Did you use version `3.7` locally? if yes, then please elaborate on why code was working fine locally w/ `3.7` and failing on AWS?